# How to group the _index and _type to the parent of _source when display elasticsearch result

Tags: elasticsearch

Assumed that I need to query multiple index and doc like below, 
I want to group the _source element into their own _index, _type as a parent, but somehow it given every index, type at every block, it is difficult for me to manage the result

`GET /index_1,index_2,hockey,bookdb_index/_search?size=200`

```
        {
        "_index": "hockey",
        "_type": "player",
        "_id": "10",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "first": "mikael",
            "last": "backlund",
            "goals": [
                3,
                15,
                13
            ],
            ...
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": "bookdb_index",
        "_type": "book",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "title": "Taming Text:...
        }
    },
```

How can I group the index and type as a parent and the _source is a child element

```
"hockey": {
    "player": [{
       "first": "mikael",
        "last": "backlund",
        "goals": [
            3,
            15,
            13
        ] }
      }, { "first": ...

      }]
}, 
"bookdb_index": { ...
```

Comment: As my understand, ES not support this operate

Answer (score 0):

I have created client for this purpose and etc.

[Nginx Elastic Client](https://github.com/Taymindis/nginx-elastic-client)

It is pure elasticsearch query write in nginx.conf, upstream to elastic server, 
you can opt `index_docs` to get the result you want. See the readme for more info.

```
 location /test {
    elastic_pass http://elastic_upstream;
    elastic_send POST /testindex/testdoc/_search?size=100 index_docs;

    elastic_query '{"query":
       {
        "match_all": {}
       }
    }';
 }
```